# unable to display the table which contains "message data" to chart while clicking on the particular part

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When we click on a particular month in a chart then it need to display depends upon the specific month and the same "constant.js". Could you please help me in this to display some of the data in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see the value of `this.props.messages` is `undefined`. So that's why you are not able to display records in table. Because you are trying to pull data from `this.state.messages` and it's `undefined`.

Once you fix it then it will auto display in the table.

Here I have created working demo for you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-pine-krhfq

Comment: Can you help me in fixing it?

Comment: Let me know what is the purpose of API call `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`?

Comment: i've saw in some example, when connecting to the backend they will be placing the API link in this given link "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" . As of now there is no use for the charts

Comment: I have updated my answer with working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-pine-krhfq. Let me know is it work for you?

Comment: Can you please Vote Up this answer. So it will be helpful to other developer as well.